# How to find the mean and reshape an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, mean, reshape

I have an array of the shape `(901, 201, 3, 20)`.

Please, how can I find the mean of the third matrix to give me `(901, 201, 20)` or `(901, 201, 1, 20)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using numpy, this is quite easy using [numpy.mean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html). The first argument would be the array, and as second argument you specify the axis over which to take the mean.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((901, 201, 3, 20))
b = np.mean(a, axis=2)

print(b.shape) # (901, 201, 20)
```

I recommend you to take a look at the documentation. You could for example also use the keepdims argument to keep the dimension of the axis, resulting in a shape of (901, 201, 1, 20). Hope this helps